# How to empty foxpro db table?

Tags: database, foxpro

How can i empty the whole foxpro db table using any trigger or stored procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to empty a FoxPro table is first by getting exclusive access (ie no-one else has the file open and you can USE yourTable EXCLUSIVE): then you can use the [ZAP command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00c5e99f%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can also

```
use table
Delete all
```

But they wont be fully deleted until a deleted until `PACK` is issued